# Jenkins pipeline - Separating unit tests and integration test results

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using JenkinsFile to manage our pipeline.
Since, we integrated maven-failsafe-plugin to run the unit tests and integration tests separately, we get separate result reports from both plugins.
This is how i configured the same in JenkinsFile in the post section:

```
junit testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml, **/target/failsafe-reports/*.xml'
```

I would have expected Jenkins to show unit tests and integration tests separately, but unfortunately, Jenkins merges the results of both XML and there is no clear distinction between unit test and integration tests.
We want our builds to have a separate view on Integration tests results.
Is there anyway to do that with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know a way how to do that in Jenkins itself, but maybe a workaround. After you use `mvn clean verify` you can use `mvn site` in a jenkins pipeline and build a HTML representation. These testresults are splitted between failsafe and surefire and you can open it directly from your workspace and look into the diffrent results from failsafe and surefire plugin.

Comment: unfortunately, our requirement was for Jenkins itself (still don't have a solution there :), locally, it works with the solution you proposed

Comment: ya, its not really the solution for your problem, but somewhat of a workaround.Maybe it helps someone who is looking for a local solution :)